# Trying to tune my word2vec model using GridSearchCV but I am getting this error in python3

Tags: python, performance, machine-learning, word2vec, hyperparameters

**My Code:**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from gensim.sklearn_api import W2VTransformer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, make_scorer

s_obj = W2VTransformer()

params_grid = {
    'size': [100,200,300],
    'window':[10,15,20],
    'min_count': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    'workers': [10,20],
    'sg':[0,1],
    'negative': [2,3,4,6,5],
    'sample':[1e-5]    
}

s_model = GridSearchCV(s_obj, params_grid, cv=3, 
                       scoring=make_scorer(accuracy_score))
s_model.fit(sentences)

print(s_model.best_params_)
```

**Error is :** `" TypeError: _score() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_true' "`

> PS: I reached the point that the error is showing something about
> y_true i.e needed a labelled data then I am not having labelled data,
> working on unsupervised learning, so if I am correct then do we have
> any other library to tune the unsupervised model?

full traceback

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-230-37cafb83162e> in <module>
     14 
     15 s_model = GridSearchCV(s_obj,params_grid,cv=3,scoring=make_scorer(accuracy_score))
---> 16 s_model.fit(train)
     17 
     18 print(s_model.best_params_)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    734                 return results
    735 
--> 736             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    737 
    738         # For multi-metric evaluation, store the best_index_, best_params_ and

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1186     def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1187         """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
-> 1188         evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
   1189 
   1190 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in evaluate_candidates(candidate_params)
    706                               n_splits, n_candidates, n_candidates * n_splits))
    707 
--> 708                 out = parallel(delayed(_fit_and_score)(clone(base_estimator),
    709                                                        X, y,
    710                                                        train=train, test=test,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1039             # remaining jobs.
   1040             self._iterating = False
-> 1041             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1042                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1043 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    857                 return False
    858             else:
--> 859                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    860                 return True
    861 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    775         with self._lock:
    776             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 777             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    778             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    779             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    206     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    207         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 208         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    209         if callback:
    210             callback(result)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    570         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    571         # arguments in memory
--> 572         self.results = batch()
    573 
    574     def get(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    260         # change the default number of processes to -1
    261         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 262             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    263                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    264 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    260         # change the default number of processes to -1
    261         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
--> 262             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
    263                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    264 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, return_estimator, error_score)
    558     else:
    559         fit_time = time.time() - start_time
--> 560         test_scores = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
    561         score_time = time.time() - start_time - fit_time
    562         if return_train_score:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
    603         scorer = _MultimetricScorer(**scorer)
    604     if y_test is None:
--> 605         scores = scorer(estimator, X_test)
    606     else:
    607         scores = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py in __call__(self, estimator, *args, **kwargs)
     85         for name, scorer in self._scorers.items():
     86             if isinstance(scorer, _BaseScorer):
---> 87                 score = scorer._score(cached_call, estimator,
     88                                       *args, **kwargs)
     89             else:

TypeError: _score() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_true'
```

*Can anyone help me to solve this issue?*

Comment: You should include the full error message, including traceback showing involved code-lines/line-numbers/source-files, in your question as quoted text. That usually helps narrow the causes & involved code/variables very well. But also: `Word2Vec` is an unsupervised technique. Scoring typically requires some 'gold standard' of desired results, against which to evaluate a result as 'accurate' or not. What is the definition of 'accuracy' you want your `Word2Vec` models to match? How are you injecting those 'true' answers into the process? (I don't see that in your code.)

Comment: hi @gojomo
I have added the traceback.
now can you help me what does this mean "How are you injecting those 'true' answers into the process?"
thanks for the reply